# i changed font in intellij, but weird

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, size, windows-10

i use intellij idea in windows10.
i want to use monaco font in intellij.
So I changed the font setting for use monaco font.
The change is successful but a little strange.
When i use code completion, item font is so small.

---

[image]

---

How can I increase the font size? or can I solve this problem?
Can I use Monaco fonts in intellij on windows10?

Comment: [File a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) attached.

Comment: Try to change the **line spacing** from Settings->Editor->Colors and Fonts->Font->Line Spacing

Comment: @EngineerDollery No offence, maybe it's not the case here, but some people need to change their font settings due to eye disorders. Just saying...

Comment: @EngineerDollery Cool, before I replied, I kept wondering for a couple of minutes whether it was a troll comment, bad day at work (even tho' it's Fri), a joke, or something else, so yes, a smile would've cleared that up. Have a nice weekend everyone